# Reference built-in types by module/namespace

Tags: elm

What I wan't to do is pretty much this:

```elm
type alias String =
    { prop: String -- here I want a native String
    }
```

This won't work since the compiler naturally assumes it's recursive. I assumed some module would expose the native type, but neither `Basics.String` nor `String.String` works.

So, is there a way to have your own types use the same name as a native type and still reference the native one?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure this is a great idea, from a readability perspective, but to address the question of whether it's possible, it will work if you create an alias for `String` in a different module.

Something like this will work:

#### Alias.elm

```
module Alias exposing (..)

type alias ElmString = 
    String
```

#### Main.elm

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Alias exposing (ElmString)

type alias String = 
    { prop: ElmString
    }
```

Comment: the alias is named `ElmString`, which is imported but not used ... so how does it help disambiguate `type alias String = 
    { prop: String
    }` ?

Comment: I assume you mean `type alias String = { prop: ElmString}`. That is an interesting solution; I could basically create my own "Basics" module. It isn't quite optimal for my use case though (generated code), so I'll wait a bit and see if there's any other suggestions.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren, you're right, I had the example wrong, I've fixed it.

Comment: There is no way to do this without using your own module as a namespace for a built in type, as the Alias module is doing above. The reason is that the builtin String module name is simply String and if you create a type in your own code called String the compiler forgets the built in String for that file.